# Почему не запускается расширение на сайте Яндекс?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, права-доступа

Тестовое расширение, которое просто выводит лог в консоль. На сайте поиска Яндекс или Яндекс.Музыки расширение не работает. Например, на 4PDA работает. Ошибок в консоль не приходит. Это какая-то защита или недостаток прав? Браузер также от Яндекса.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "TestEx",
    "description": "Test desc",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://4pda.ru/", "https://yandex.ru/"],
        "js": ["content-script.js"]
      }
    ]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
console.log('TestEx...');
```

Comment: Защиты у сайта быть не может. Расширение работает в изолированной области. Просто где-то ошибка. Есть один момент - у меня вывод в консоль не всегда адекватно работает в Опере, при этом в Хроме все прекрасно. Думаю это может быть баг обертками вокруг движка. Я к тому, что остальные функции будут работать адекватно. UPD: просто пишите и тестируйте в Хроме, а потом подключайте куда угодно - проверено.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg как оказалось, это новая защита у Яндекс.Браузера, [новость](https://tjournal.ru/tech/158081-yandeks-brauzer-blokiruet-rasshireniyam-dostup-k-servisam-yandeksa)

Comment: спасибо за новость. Не пользуюсь этим браузером. Но то что я описал выше у меня действительно было около года назад. При этом устанавливаю свои расширения(тестированные в Хроме) в Оперу и Firefox. А новость эту, следует донести до пользователей :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, дело в использовании Яндекс.Браузера. Согласно [новости](https://tjournal.ru/tech/158081-yandeks-brauzer-blokiruet-rasshireniyam-dostup-k-servisam-yandeksa), работа по сути любых расширений на доменах Яндекс через его Браузер заблокирована.